# No component factory found for PermissionsDialogComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular

I don't understand why this is not working. I have  PermissionsDialogComponent in entryComponent as you can see

```
import { PermissionsComponent } from "./permissions/permissions.component";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";



import { PermissionsDialogComponent } from "./permissions/permissions-dialog/permissions-dialog.component";


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "invitations",
    component: InvitationsComponent
  },
  {
    path: "userlist",
    component: UserListComponent
  },
  {
    path: "permissions",
    component: PermissionsComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [

    PermissionsComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),

  ],
  entryComponents: [PermissionsDialogComponent]
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

This is my user module which I have imported in appmodule.

Answer (score 1):

Components should be added to the declarations array

```
declarations: [
    PermissionsComponent,
    PermissionsDialogComponent 
  ]
```

Edit:

entryComponents are no longer required as of Angular 9. If you are on Angular <9 and need to use the PermissionsDialogComponent as an entry component, then leave it in entry components, but you still need to add it to declarations.